# How to Split Up Text Manim and move them, and highlight lines?

Tags: python, manim

Is it possible to make an object like, glow for a bit before it returns to normal. Kinda like a highlight feature so it would be easier to notice which line or point I am talking about in the video.

I also want to split up a text and break it into two, then move it into two different places.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an object glow, you could use [`Indicate`](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.indication.Indicate.html), which both scales the text and changes its color:

```
tex = Tex("Indicate").scale(3)
self.play(Indicate(tex))
self.wait()
```

There are also other animations that you can use to draw attention to a particular object as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.indication.html).

Since

> Text objects behave like a VGroup-like iterable of all characters in the given text. In particular, slicing is possible.

We can just slice a text object into 2 different pieces and move them separately:

```
s = Text("SplitMe")
self.play(Write(s))
self.play(ApplyMethod(s[:5].move_to, LEFT), ApplyMethod(s[5:].move_to, RIGHT))
```